# Change golang slice in another function

Tags: go

I have a slice, if i remove one element from it directly in a main function the length of slice would be cut by one. But do the remove in another function and called it in main, the length of the slice is still keep origin. Who can explain it for me? Thanks!

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    i := 0

    //copy(a[i:], a[i+1:])
    //a[len(a)-1] = 0
    //a = a[:len(a)-1]
    //fmt.Println(a)    //outputs: [2 3 4], this is correct

    f(a, i)
    fmt.Println(a) //outputs: [2 3 4 0], this is wrong!
}

func f(a []int, i int) {
    copy(a[i:], a[i+1:])
    a[len(a)-1] = 0
    a = a[:len(a)-1]
    fmt.Println(a) //outputs: [2 3 4], here still correct
}
```

[Go Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/okTAe8k6b_0)

Comment: Your function should return a new slice

Comment: See https://blog.golang.org/slices (and https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Answer (score 2):

The slice is passed by value, so changing it in your function `f` won't change it in function `main`. You can pass by pointer, like this:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    i := 0

    f(&a, i)
    fmt.Println(a)    //outputs: [2 3 4], correct
}

func f(a *[]int, i int) {
    b := *a
    copy(b[i:], b[i+1:])
    // The following line seems pointless, but ok...
    b[len(b)-1] = 0
    b = b[:len(b)-1]
    fmt.Println(b)    //outputs: [2 3 4], here still correct
    *a = b
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YOQoT1QObhe)

As suggested by @zerkms in the comments, you could also return the new slice, avoiding the use of pointers:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    i := 0

    a = f(a, i)
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func f(a []int, i int) []int {
    copy(a[i:], a[i+1:])
    // The following line seems pointless, but ok...
    a[len(a)-1] = 0
    a = a[:len(a)-1]
    fmt.Println(a)     //outputs: [2 3 4], here still correct
    return a
}
```

Comment: `The slice is passed by value` is not correct. Slices are passed by reference. It's just that `b[:len(b)-1]` creates a new slice,

Comment: @AyushGupta there's no "pass by reference" in Go.

Comment: @mkopriva not exactly. I have found that all data structures built using `make` are kind-of passed by reference. Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/r5tqggXYZdV

Comment: @AyushGupta there is no such thing as "pass by reference" in Go https://golang.org/ref/spec Your example passes slice header **by value**.

Comment: @AyushGupta What is passed by value here is the slice header, so the function gets a copy of the header, that's why changing a copy of the header, like its length for example, isn't reflected outside of the function.

Comment: @AyushGupta you are wrong; mkopriva is right. You _must_ understand that nothing on Go is ever "passed by reference". Some types have reference like _semantics_ but still are passed by value.

Comment: @AyushGupta In your example, you modify the array (using the slice), which is why the change is reflected in your main function.

Comment: @Volker Well, I learnt something today, thanks! I'll read up on this. (Also meant to tag zerkms and mkopriva but SO won't allow that)

Answer (score 0):

Not providing new solution, just trying to explain why your program is behaving the way you asked:

Let us try to understand first how the built in function ‘copy’ works  Ref: [https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy]

```
func copy(dst, src []Type) int
```

The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice into a destination slice. (As a special case, it also will copy bytes from a string to a slice of bytes.) The source and destination may overlap. Copy returns the number of elements copied, which will be the minimum of len(src) and len(dst).

Two things:
 1.  First comment the line : //a[len(a)-1] = 0

2. Second: As you are using the same array i.e as source and destination you are getting [2,3,4,4] as output as the destination array is {1,2,3,4} which got overwritten to {2,3,4,4(which is already present)}  you can try with different array’s to make it more clear to you

Comment: Thanks for not providing new solution. I know the copy will finally output [2,3,4,4], so I did `a = a[:len(a)-1]` to shorten the length of slice. I think the key point is not about the copy method. I agree they are passed by value, as i'm new to golang so I don't know how it works in low level